# How to use log4j in EJB Module?

Tags: java, log4j, ejb

I have a EJB Module using Netbeans and glassfish 3.1.2.
I need to implement log but I don't know how to configure log4j in a EJB. 
I'm having this problem when deploying:

```
SEVERE: log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [file:/C:/Users/Luis Carlos/AppData/Roaming/NetBeans/7.2/config/GF3/domain1/config/log4j.properties].
SEVERE: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (beans.RutasBean).
SEVERE: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
SEVERE: log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

It is shown in the glassfish server console.

This is the log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, FILE
log4j.logger.myapp=DEBUG
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/space/gfv3/v3setup/GlassFish3/GlassFish/domains/domain1/logs/log4j.log
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=100KB 
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=1 
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{DATE} %-5p %c{1} : %m%n
```

I tried
[this](https://blogs.oracle.com/naman/entry/configure_log4j_for_use_in)
and it says that I have to configure the properties file like this in the server admin of glassfish
`-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/log4j.properties`
but didn't work

I have a Singleton Session Bean and in the startup method I configure the log, so according to [this](http://blog.rueedlinger.ch/2010/09/initialize-log4j-with-an-ejb-3-1-startup-bean/) I have in the bean:

```
    private Logger log;
private static final String LOG4J_PROPERTIES = "/log4j.properties";

@PostConstruct
public void startup(){
    URL url = this.getClass().getResource(LOG4J_PROPERTIES);
    if(url == null || url.getFile().length() == 0) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Log4j config file "+ LOG4J_PROPERTIES +" not found");
}
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(url);
    log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
    log.info("Starting application");
    em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("BuscaBus-ejbPU");
    rutaController = new RutaJpaController(ut, em);
    actualizarCoordenadasRutas();
    ...
}
```

but still appears the same error

How can I configure log4j in a EJB enviroment?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Remove `-Dlog4j.configuration=` from your server.
2. Remove any `log4j.properties` that you might have placed into `C:/Users/Luis Carlos/AppData/Roaming/NetBeans/7.2/config/GF3/domain1/config`
3. Remove the following code:

   ```
   URL url = this.getClass().getResource(LOG4J_PROPERTIES);
   if(url == null || url.getFile().length() == 0) {
   throw new RuntimeException("Log4j config file "+ LOG4J_PROPERTIES +" not found");
   ```
4. Remove this: `PropertyConfigurator.configure(url);`

Once you're done with the aforementioned steps, your code is in the position to have Log4J automatically load its `log4j.properties` file from the **classpath**. From my experience, that's the most flexible way to go about configuring Log4J. All that's left for you to do is to ensure that `log4j.properties` indeed exists somewhere in the classpath.

You have the following options:

1. Place the `log4j.properties` file inside the default package of your EJB module. That way, the `log4j.properties` file will be packaged along with your application. There are pros and cons to this, but that's a different story (which belongs, most likely, in a different Q&A thread).
2. Place the `log4j.properties` in some directory on your file system, and add that directory to your server's classpath. Follow the GlassFish documentation about how to do that.

If you insist to have the `log4j.properties` file referred-to by a URL, then reinstate the `-Dlog4j.configuration=` directive. Make sure that the URL you provide, specifying the `log4j.properties` file, **actually exists**. Also, specify `-Dlog4j.debug=true`; that will provide you with debugging information from Log4J itself, telling you exactly what it is doing.